# Where and if clause in SQL query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure, let's say I have a **flag**, which can be either **0** or **1**

If **1**, then I want to `select * from table A where name = 'blah'`.
If **0**, then I would want to `select * from table A where name = blah and age = 13`.

Is there a way I can add `and age = 13` to a stored procedure query?

This is what I have currently.

```
IF @flag = 1
  SELECT * from A where name = 'blah'

ELSE 
  SELECT * from A where name = 'blah' and age = 13
```

I would like to know for cases where query becomes really long, and so copying and pasting with few more likes for `ELSE` case is very inefficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * from A 
where name = 'blah' 
and (@flag = 1 or age = 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `Case statement`;

```
Select * from A
Where Name = 'blah' And Age = Case @flag when 1 then Age else 13 end
```

Comment: This solution works well when comparing a value to one of several different columns (depending on a flag). Although, I would use the `OR` option in this specific case (simpler).

Comment: I agree with both of you and posted as it is bit different.